# How to render a foo.md markdown file in react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, r-markdown

I have several .md files (containing long texts) and I want to render them through react. I tried to use markedown-it but the loader returns an error. Here is the webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var subscript = require('markdown-it');
var superscript = require('markdown-it');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/first.jsx'],
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    output: { path: __dirname+"/app", filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] },
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {   test:   /\.md/,
                loader: 'markdown-it'
            }
        ]
    },
    'markdown-it': {
        preset: 'default',
        typographer: true,
        use: [subscript, superscript]
    }
};
```

Is there something wrong with that file? How else I can add my *.md files to react?

After reading http://www.shoutinginfrench.com/today-i-made-react-load-markdown/ I tried to use markdown-loader. Following that, I added this to webpack.config file:

```
{   test: /\.md$/,
   loader: "html!markdown"
}
```

which worked with no problem. Then I tried to add the markdown file to the react component as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import markdownFile from './test-file.md';
 export const Test = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup(){
         return { __html: markdownFile };
     },
     render() {
         return (
             <div className="something">
                 <div className="row">
                     <div className="col-10">
                         <div dangerouslySetInnerHtml={this.rawMarkup()} />
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
     }
 });
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/tst.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'html' in /Users/..../src/components
 @ ./src/components/tst.jsx 14:15-39
```

How can I fix it?!

Comment: And why you don't use markdown-ir-sub and markdown-it-sup?

Comment: A loader is the right way to do it. Can you give us more info about the error you're getting? Stack trace?

Comment: Here is part of the error:  ERROR   in ./~/markdown-it/~/entities/maps/entities.json
Module parse failed: /Users/..../node_modules/markdown-it/node_modules/entities/maps/entities.json Line 1: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {"Aacute":"\u00C1","aacute":"\u00E1","Abreve":"\u0102","abr........

Comment: My bad!! I was editing the file and testing and forgot to revert the changes! So now using "markdown-ir-sub" and "markdown-it-sup" it works with no error. Now how can I tell react to render the md file?

Comment: I added my other try with markdown-loader to the main question. Does anyone know how to fix the new issue?

Comment: @sarah Have you installed `html-loader` as well?

Comment: @joonki thanks! No I didn't have html-loader installed! Just installed it and also installed "file-loader". Now I'm not getting any error but the page doesn't show the md file...

Comment: @Sarah Is this going to be frontend only? One option is to prerender the Markdown as React syntax into your `index.html`. This can be a very neat way to handle it. I've used [remark-react](https://github.com/mapbox/remark-react) for this purpose. You can find the full setup at my [boilerplate](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate).

Answer (score 2):

add `{ test: /\.md$/, loader: "html!markdown" },{ test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" }`    to your webpack.config.js .

```
npm install react-markdown --save-dev
```

Comment: You'll want to install the `markdown-loader` package instead. Also make sure you have `html-loader` for this to work